# ANDROID: Changing TextView on click of a button

Tags: android, button

First all i'm new to Android programming, so my level of coding isn't too great :p
I have a deck of cards class in which I want to return the value of the card drawn into a text view.

```
cardValue = "The " + numString + " of " + suitString;
    return cardValue;
```

This is the end of the method drawCard in my deck class.
In my virtualDeck class, I have created an instance of this class,

```
final textdeck deck = new textdeck();
        String value = deck.drawCard();
```

What i'm trying to do is create a button on the virtualDeck class, that once clicked will run the drawCard method from the textDeck class, and return the result into a textView. With each time the button is clicked, having the textView change to print the new value.

I can quite seem to get my head around how to do this.
Any help is much appreciated.
Cheers.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you having trouble creating the button, setting the new text, or both? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Currently in my app, all I have needed buttons for is to link to other pages, so creating a button to run a method, I have tried

ImageButton DrawCard = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.drawcard);
        DrawCard.setOnClickListener(new android.widget.Button.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View v) {
                deck.drawCard();
                }});

Its mainly getting the return statement from one java class onto another activities class text view that im unsure of how to do.
Let me know how you wish me to be more specific if need be. :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this example of how to setup a TextView helps:

In your main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/card"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In your source (TextViewExample.java)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class TextViewExample extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Do all your deck setup here
        String value = "8 of Spades";

        //New textView
        TextView cardDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.card);

        //Update Text
        cardDisplay.setText(value);

    }
}
```

Comment: `findControlById(R.id.card)` may return null, so you have to check `if (cardDisplay != null) { ... } ` to avoid app crash.

Comment: Do you mean findViewById? cardDisplay will never be null because it's declared in the main.xml file and its int is available in the R.Java file which is automatically generated.  I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: I thought that so at first, but that was the reason of crashes for me. Had do clear and rebuild project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do, but this is how you change the view via button:

```
    Button nextButton =(Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Where next is the Button created inside the current layout.
Then in the onclick listener:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondIntent.class);                                
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

and SecondIntent is the name of the second class you are calling. That class can have its own view because it can call setContentView().

The only thing is to make sure that you open up the AndroidManifest.xml and add the following in the  tag

`<activity android:name=".SecondIntent"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>`

Adding that to the manifest will let android know that the other activity exists.

Now if you want to open the second view and be able to close the second view to return to the first, only add `finish()` to the second activity and not the first.

Good luck!
-A Fellow Android Noob